# how to get id from local storage

Tags: javascript

I am using redux with next.js .
this is may code for prfileSlice .

```
import axios from "axios";
import { base_url } from "@/utils/base_url";

const getProfile = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${base_url}user/${id}`)

    return response.data;
}



const profileService = {

    getProfile,
};
export default profileService;
```

but it cant find id . What to do to get id from localstorage;

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from `localStorage` you need to know at which key it is stored. Let's say your id is stored at key "id" then you get it like that:

```
const storedId = localStorage.getItem("id");
```

Note that if there is no such key in the storage, then `null` will be returned, don't forget to account for that.

In the code that you provided, `getProfile` function does not have an argument `id` that you are using in the template string of the response. You should add it to the list of arguments.

After that, to pass this id to the function you need to first get value from storage, as described before and then pass it to your function:

```
let profile = await getProfile(storedId);
```

You can read more about localStorage at [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)